# Last-Of Type and Last-Of-Child

Tags: html, css

**HTML:**

```
<div class="plan-box">
    <h3>...</h3>
    <p>...</p>
</div>

<div class="plan-box">
    <h3>...</h3>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.plan-box:last-of-type {
    ...
}
```

In the above CSS code if I use `last-of-type` or `last-child` css selector on `.plan-box` will that select the `last-child` in both the `.plan-box` div which is the paragraph or will it select the second `.plan-box` div in the HTML code?

Comment: You should test it and find out.

Comment: You can find it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ice_frog/pkgvdrmw/), it will second one.

Comment: Oh arite, Thanks! I got it now. @ShekharPankaj So if I had three .plan-box divs and I wanted to select the second one I would have to JS for that.

Comment: @KB3 No you wouldn't. You could use [nth child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: @JamieBarker Ohh right. I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.plan-box:last-child` Selects last of `plan.box` element

`.plan-box :last-child` Selects last elements in all of `plan.box` elements

[Css Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: I tried using last-child but it still selected the last of the .plan-box element.

Comment: Did you pay attention to space between .plan-box and :last-child ? Here is the example. https://jsfiddle.net/1kdng2bj/

Comment: I missed that space! So for all selectors you need to space after the css class or element you are selecting but for psuedo classes you do not need a space?

Comment: Space about selection. Here is the detail http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp. Psuedo classes should always stick with element.  `:last-child` equals `*:last-child` actually.

Answer (score 0):

It will select second `.plan-box` `div` in the HTML code.

See the [Link here](https://jsfiddle.net/z3Lopyu0/)

Again you can easily select any child `div` with **CSS** .Example is [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xcL0uzyx/1/)
I have used here `.plan-box:nth-child(2) {}` for select second `div`.